# std::vector<Eigen::Matrix4f> allocated memory but fails to access its elements

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, segmentation-fault, eigen

I created a vector which contains 100 Eigen::Matrix4f. But when I use `transforms[i]` to access its elements, the programme shows "core dumped: segmentation fault". When I use `push_back()` function to initialize it, it works well.
I checked the size of the vector. It is 100. I am confused about it.

It is in Ubuntu 16.04. I use CMake + GCC to compile it.

Segmentation fault C++ code

```
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix4f> transforms(100);
//transforms.size() is 100. I checked it.
for(int i = 0; i < transforms.size(); i++)
{
    //I use transforms[i] to access the element in transforms.
    transforms[i] = a_function_returns_a_valid_Matrix4f();
}
```

The following code works by using `std::vector::push_back()`.

```
std::vector<Eigen::Matrix4f> transforms;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    //When I use push_back() to initialize transforms, it works.
    transforms.push_back(a_function_returns_a_valid_Matrix4f());
}
```

It seems `std::vector` allocated the memory correctly. I checked its size.
But failed to access its element by using `transforms[i]`.

Comment: Is it faster to allocate 100 Matrix4f objects at the beginning of the construction of a std::vector container than using push_back in a loop?

Comment: 1. Use [at](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) instead of `[i]`. 2. Can you provide an error log? it's possible that a_function_returns_a_valid_Matrix4f() is causing the segmentation fault. 3. Do you have any other threads in this code that access `transforms`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]! Did you disable assertions (i.e., compiled with `-DNDEBUG`)? Could be a simple alignment issue. If you want to use `.push_back()` you can use `.reserve(100)` at the beginning to avoid re-allocations.

Comment: @hackela `sizeof(transforms)` is typically `3*sizeof(void*)`, so completely wrong here. `transforms.size()` is correct.

Comment: Are you using C++11? Check this out: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html